# Как передать в функцию (или класс), имеющую несколько предустановленных аргументов, только один, причем конкретный, а не первый

Tags: python

```
def func(a=4 , b=3):
    a = a + 1
    b = b * 5
    return a, b
print(func())
```

Я хочу передать аргумент `b`, при вызове функции, оставив `а` по умолчанию (`а=4`). Как это сделать?

Если передать только один аргумент, то замениться первый, а второй останется предустановленным.

Answer (score 6):

Назвать его по имени:

```
func(b=35)
```